# Run custom one time script django

Tags: python, django

I want to run a custom one time script (to read from Excel file and write to DB) the problem is when i run

- `python manage.py shell < polygon/run.py`

I can't find xlrd package

```
Error:
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jurabek/Project/hrm/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jurabek/Project/hrm/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jurabek/Project/hrm/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jurabek/Project/hrm/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jurabek/Project/hrm/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 92, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in run
NameError: name 'xlrd' is not defined
```

Code

```
..imports from apps

import xlrd

loc = ('users.xlsx')

def run():
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)

    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    print(sheet.cell_value(0, 0))


run()
```

The project structure is

```
.venv
apps/
 -- all my apps
polygon/
  run.py
manage.py
settings/
```

UPDATE the problem is solved. Error was because manage.py didn't see the users.xlsx, changed to polygon/users.xlsx and it worked

Thank you!

Comment: use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan I've updated the question, I've figured out how to run the script, but the problem now with importing xlrd package

Comment: `pip install xlrd`

Comment: @Exprator Already did so

Comment: `python -m pip list`, to verify `pip` uses the correct Python (i.e., is `xlrd` listed?)

Comment: Your update on the solution doesn't make sense, given the listed traceback. Could you explain the traceback?

Comment: @Jay Please verify you install it in your virtual environment and is it active or not? and check is it installed or not with this command `pip freeze` after activation of the virtual environment